# WPF binding doesn't work

Tags: wpf, binding

I have simplified example:

XAML:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="cb" />
<Button Name="button1" Click="button1_Click" />
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyObject> collection = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        collection.Add(new MyObject(true));
        //grid.DataContext = collection[0];
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        collection[0].IsSelected = false;
    }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public MyObject(bool isSelected)
    {
        this.IsSelected = isSelected;
    }
}
```

**The cb.IsChecked doesn't change by button clicking though the collection[0].IsSelected is changed.**

Even if I uncomment grid.DataContext = collection[0]; - nothing changed.

In real example I have the same checkbox in the item template of a listbox. So the behaviour is the same - the selection of checkboxes don't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your MyObject type

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following codes:

```
public class MyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    private bool _isSelected;

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }

    public MyObject(bool isSelected)
    {
        this.IsSelected = isSelected;
    }
}
```